# Is there a good cloud based reverse proxy for webhook development?

Tags: server, reverse-proxy

Is there any cheap cloud based reverse proxy service I can use for localhost software development. Ideally I would like to have a server running on my laptop and be able to address it via an https url with domain. The main reason is to test integrations with 3rd party vendors that make calls to our service endpoints (shopify webhooks for example). I cant seem to find anything that isnt 1k$+ per year.

Lets say my ip is:
1.2.3.4

I **dont** need this to work inside the company VPN. Assume 1.2.3.4 is a publicly addressable IP address. It might change when I restart but I dont mind updating the new IP in the reverse proxy every few days.

I would like to be able to reach that IP address using some URL like this (where the provider itself creates the subdomain I specify):
https://mysubdomain.cloudreverseproxy.com

So the cloud proxy would need to be able to provide the SSL certificate and route the request to whatever IP address I specify. Its a work computer so I cant install anything deemed a security risk (I got in some trouble for installing ngrok app for instance).

I have used apache and nginx and am familiar with those configurations but I really need basic routing and can set up my own reverse proxy on localhost once the request gets to me.

Ive tried a few things. Dyn DNS is sort of what I want but I cant set up SSL certs. Ngrok basically works but I dont think I can set up the IP statically and it requires me to install software on the work computer that is not allowed by my company.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found AWS has an API gateway feature [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/http-api-develop.html). They provide an HTTPS url for your API and you can set up rules for where to forward inbound requests including http endpoints not living in AWS. I just need to keep this configured with my computer IP address and update when my IP changes. Also need to be disconnected from my companies VPN.